# Understanding Precision and Recall Results on a Binary Classifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, precision-recall

I know the difference between Precision and Recall metrics in Machine Learning. One optimizes on False Positives and other on False Negative. In Statistics it is called as optimizing on Type I or Type II error.

However, I am a but confused on under what circumstances one can get complete opposite Precision and Recall? Like Precision =1 and Recall=0?.

Let me iterate:

```
precision = true positives / (true positives + false positives)

recall = true positives / (true positives + false negatives)
```

And here is the Confusion Matrix

```
  predicted
            (+)   (-)
            ---------
       (+) | TP | FN |
actual      ---------
       (-) | FP | TN |
            ---------
```

Now, if Precision is =1 for a classifier for the positive (1) class, that means, there are no FP and all predicted labels are TP.

Then how can for the same positive class the Recall be 0? If there is already some TP being predicted, in fact as per Precision all predicted ones are TP only, then for Recall, we would have numerator non zero, then under what circumstances can one get Recall 0 then for the same classifier positive class?

To give some context, I ran a Logistic regression classifier for a binary classification problem. I had some 23K training data with 774 features. 770 features are binary or dummy variables.

And this is the distribution of my class labels:

```
1    20429
0    12559
```

And here is the confusion matrix and accuracy values after a 5 fold grid search on some 25 combination of Hyper parameter values.

```
The mean train scores are [ 0.66883049  0.54314532  0.67008959  0.63187226  0.63100366  0.53165968
  0.54131812  0.55507725  0.5578254   0.57663273  0.57247462  0.57230056
  0.54402055  0.5762753   0.50925733  0.45781882  0.39366017  0.39037968
  0.3919818   0.38878762  0.39784982  0.39506755  0.48238147  0.38932944
  0.39801223]

The mean validation scores are [ 0.66445801  0.54107661  0.66878871  0.63184791  0.6305487   0.5291239
  0.53899788  0.55324585  0.55822615  0.57784418  0.57269066  0.57312373
  0.54536399  0.57593868  0.50790351  0.45727773  0.39318349  0.38906933
  0.39214413  0.38924256  0.39794725  0.39461262  0.4827855   0.38811658
  0.39812048]

The score on held out data is: 0.6687887055562773
 Hyper-Parameters for Best Score : {'alpha': 0.0001, 'l1_ratio': 0.45}

The accuracy of sgd on test data is: 0.37526523188845107

Classification Metrics for sgd :
             precision    recall  f1-score   support

          0       0.38      1.00      0.55      3712
          1       1.00      0.00      0.00      6185

avg / total       0.77      0.38      0.21      9897
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand. If precision =1, then it's only when FP=0. And TP is not 0. When Recall=0, it means TP=0. Thats contradictory

Answer (score 2):

The output you've posted is rounded to 2 decimal places, so it's likely that you have precision = 1 and recall equal to say 0.001. This could happen for example if you only had one case (correctly) predicted as 1, and everything else predicted as 0. So you have a very high false positive rate, and your recall is 1/6185 which is close to 0.

Comment: You mean to to say False negative rate for recall to be 0 as Recall is concerning FN. 

I think you have a point here. It can be that. Which means the Precision recall value here are useless. Even if I focus on an algorithm which is high precision, such precision for just 1 or two correct values mean nothing. 

Also, why do you think this can be the case with such bad performance? I tried Random forest and it gave 75% accuracy unlike 37 here. So is it because of having non linear decision boundary which RF finds and linear logistic as used here can't giving to bad performance?

Comment: precision and recall are not useless, the recall of zero is telling you that your model is terrible. there are many reasons logistic regression isn't working, it could be nonlinearity, could be outliers, hard to say

Comment: Hmm. One last question. When I run my SVM algo, irrespective of how many times I do the train test spit which might cause different samples to come and train again, SVM final chosen model is always same. But when I run logistic it differs with different train test split. I am not sure why would that be. Like you see above the results are bad. I ran the logistic training again and now I got 73% accuracy with different alpha and l1_ratio values. Why would model change if underlying data is same, just different train testa split might have happened.

Comment: hard to say without seeing your data but it could be due to outliers, svm is not affected by these however LR is, so it could be whether the outliers are chosen for the training set.

Comment: Ok I checked. Even in train test split, I have a random_state=42. So that means if gets the same random sampling overtime I run train test split. So then the data remains same. Then why should the model change if I retrain again.

Comment: Even for SVM it is changing. That is weird. If the data remains same, then the model should not change even if you retrain it

Comment: not sure, there might be another random process somewhere you're not setting `random_state` for, you could try using `random.seed` at the start of your code to control for this.